# VUE with vue-rx / rxjs : How to create a subscription with $watchAsObservable using filter and interval

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-observables, vue-rx

I need the help in the following vue-rx / RxJs question.

I have to make a subscription in vue-rx that watches a props value, and when it is true then it calls a http request in every 500 ms, and stops it when it is false, or when the returned value is 'COMPLETED'.

I tried something like this:

```
export default {
  props: ['started'],
  subscriptions() {
   return {
    currentHttpState: this.$watchAsObservable('started')
                      .pipe(pluck('newValue'),filter(value => value === false))
                      .switchMap(() => interval(500).pipe(switchMap(() => this.callHttpRequest()),distinctUntilChanged())),
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with vue (or vue-rx), so this may just be half the answer (the RxJS bit).

I'm assuming `this.$watchAsObservable('started')` with `pluck('newValue')` is a stream of `true` and `false`? (reflecting the value of the `started` prop)

If so, I would use switchMap to switch between an interval/timer and nothing.

```
currentHttpState: this.$watchAsObservable('started').pipe(
  pluck('newValue'),
  map(val => val? timer(0,500) : EMPTY),
  switchMap(timer$ => timer$.pipe(
    switchMap(_ => this.callHttpRequest()),
    takeWhile(result => result.status !== 'COMPLETED')
  )
)
```

that second switchMap will have the effect that if a call takes over 500ms to complete, it will be dropped and you'll never see the results. This also unsubscribed if the `takeWhile()` condition isn't met - so you'll have to change that to meet your specific requirements.

Comment: Thanks Mrk Sef, it works like a charm! Only one ')' was missing.